# PHP Newbies: How to write good code

Tags: php, coding-style

Since many PHP-related questions are very basic here, I'd propose to prepare a collection of tips and tricks.

This might be a starting point:

- **Check as much input parameters** of as much methods as possible (see [assert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php)).
- **Log all errors** to a log-file and visualize it using your admin backend (see [set_error_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)).
- **Use type-hints** as often as possible (see [type-hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php))
- Set the **error level** to the absolute maximum. Then code in such a way, that not a single warning appears (see [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)).
- Learn why and how PHP **implements and converts data types** (see [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [string conversions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion))

Thus the question is: What should PHP newbies better do?

**UPDATE-1**

Since quite some people reviewed this question, I'd **propose to reopen** it. Please click on the respective link below.

Comment: As long as SO doesn't recommend visiting this page before posting PHP questions I don't think the quality of Qs will change. But at least you can refer to this page...

Comment: @yi_H: Yes, might be true. Let's see how much stuff people contribute.

Comment: I am in no way officially stating that this question is more appropriate for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), but you might try there.  I think this might make a good community wiki, kind of like [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)

Comment: @Renesis: Hm, too bad. Yes, that's what I tried to prepare (not for me ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Test

You should better test your code, probably practicing [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). You can do this thanks to [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/). Keep in mind [Uncle Bob's three rules](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd) to practice TDD.

> 1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
> 2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
> 3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.
>
> You must begin by writing a unit test for the functionality that you
>   intend to write. But by rule 2, you can't write very much of that unit
>   test. As soon as the unit test code fails to compile, or fails an
>   assertion, you must stop and write production code. But by rule 3 you
>   can only write the production code that makes the test compile or
>   pass, and no more.
>
> If you think about this you will realize that you simply cannot write
>   very much code at all without compiling and executing something.
>   Indeed, this is really the point. In everything we do, whether writing
>   tests, writing production code, or refactoring, we keep the system
>   executing at all times. The time between running tests is on the order
>   of seconds, or minutes. Even 10 minutes is too long.

You should try to have high [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage). PHPUnit can also do [code coverage analyses](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) thanks to [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). [Refactoring code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) that is [smelly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html)([list](http://industriallogic.com/papers/smellstorefactorings.pdf)) should be easy, because of your test-cases which are already present.

### Security

- Learn [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project)
- Learn [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to prevent [SQL-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- Learn [Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) to prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
- Learn how to prevent [CSRF](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries).
- Learn about [http-only](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) cookies and how to [use in PHP](http://ilia.ws/archives/121-httpOnly-cookie-flag-support-in-PHP-5.2.html).

### Performance

- Learn and use [APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator)

> Caching the compiled bytecode of PHP scripts to avoid the overhead of
>   parsing and compiling source code on each request (some or all of
>   which may never even be executed). To further improve performance, the
>   cached code is stored in shared memory and directly executed from
>   there, minimizing the amount of slow disk reads and memory copying at
>   runtime.

- Learn to use distributed memory caching system like [Redis](http://redis.io) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org).
- Learn to just [tackle low hanging fruit](http://talks.php.net/show/confoo10) and forget about [silly micro-optimizations](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

> The famous quotation, "We should forget about small efficiencies, say
>   about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all
>   evil", by Donald Knuth,[6](http://xdebug.org/) has also been mistakenly attributed to
>   Hoare (by Knuth himself), although Hoare disclaims authorship.

- Understand that PHP is just a tool in your toolbox and is not the best solution for all your problems. For example hanging requests(long-polling) can not be implemented efficiently in PHP and that's why [Facebook decided to implement chat in Erlang instead of PHP](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/31/EugeneLetuchy-ErlangatFacebook.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

- Learn how to do tracing (`echo`, `print_r`). Invaluable.
- Check for errors after executing db queries (or better: write your own query function which automatically checks this. or still better: use some library for building queries).
- Know the difference between result mysql resource, result set and result row.