# How to pass extra post data when using Multipart in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm Using the below code in Android, retrofit, to upload an image:

```
 @Multipart 
 @POST("uploadimage") 
 Call<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

But what if I need to send extra data, such as Image Description along with the request?

I Was not able to use @Field, that is i tried like this:

```
@Multipart 
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("uploadimage") 
Call<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(@PartMapMap<String,RequestBody> map,
@Field("description")String desc);
```

I got an error stating that only one annotation is allowed. That is either @Multipart or @FormUrlEncoded.

Comment: check this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Part instead of @Field

```
@Multipart 
@POST("uploadimage") 
Call<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map, @Part("description") String description);
```

Comment: Thank you,can you tell how do i use it in php? @Part description?

Comment: you can look into this question for that https://stackoverflow.com/q/6694839/6207294

Comment: Quite not clear, but for now I'm going with @Headers, since i know to handle them in php.